# Homotopy equivalence of closed curves

Tags: homotopy-theory

Consider the family $$C_{\alpha}:\big({2(\alpha-\cos{t})\,\cos{t},\,2(\alpha-\cos{t})\,\sin{t}}\big)\,,\;t\in[0,2\pi]\,,\;\alpha\in\mathbb{R},$$ of closed parametric curves. Let $X_{\alpha}$ is the image set of $C_{\alpha}$ equiped with the induced topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

1. For which values of $\alpha$ these topological spaces $X_{\alpha}$ are homotopy-equivalent to  topological space  $X_{0.5}$?
2. For those spaces which are homotopy-equivalent to $X_{0.5}$ provide a homotopy equivalence.

In the figure below depicted $6$ curves of the family $C_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha\in\{{0.5,0.6,1.0,0.3,1.3}\}$.

Note: This is not a homework exercise. I've got an outline of solution.

Edit: I had to clarify my question. Thanks to John Palmieri's remarks.

[image]

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible, so any two maps from any space into $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homotopic. Do you mean to ask about homotopy with some extra condition? Path homotopy?

Comment: @John Palmieri Yes. I apologize if it isn't clear that I mean path-homotopy. Every (image of the) parametric curve is considered as a topological space equiped with the induced topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thank you for your remark.

Comment: Again, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible, so every path is homotopic to the constant path. Use the straight-line homotopy, for example. So they're all homotopic.

Comment: @John Palmieri Thanks, again. So, any two of these curves are homotopic but not always homeomorphic.

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean to ask about these curves as individual topological spaces, not as maps into $\mathbb{R}^2$. That’s potentially more interesting.

Comment: @John Palmieri That's right! I apologize because was my mistake that I wasn't clear about what I'm asking. The image set of every parametric curve equipped with the induced topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is considered a topological space. What I'm asking is homotopy equivalence between these spaces, i.e. homotopy equivalent spaces. And of cource is far more interesting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I give an outline of solution:*

To handle the problem easier, for $\alpha\in({-1,1})$  we consider the below  differentiable parametrization of the given curves:
\begin{align*}
 R_{\alpha}&:[0,2\pi]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2\,;\\
 &t\longmapsto R_{\alpha}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
  2\big({\alpha-\cos({t+\arccos{\alpha}})}\big)\,\cos({t+\arccos{\alpha}})\\ 2\big({\alpha-\cos({t+\arccos{\alpha}})}\big)\,\sin({t+\arccos{\alpha}})
 \end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{align*}
We observe that $R_{\alpha}(0)=R_{\alpha}(2\pi)=(0,0)$. Also, for every $\alpha\in({-1,1})$, the curve $R_{\alpha}$ makes two rounds with intersection point at $(0,0)$. For $\alpha\in({-\infty,-1}]\cup [{1,+\infty})$ the curve $C_{\alpha}$ is simple closed continuous curve.

We claim that the space $X_{\alpha}$ is homotopy-equivalent to  space  $X_{0.5}$, iff $\alpha\in({-1,1})$.

First we claim that, for $\alpha\in({-\infty,-1}]\cup [{1,+\infty})$ doesn't exist a continuous function $f_{\alpha}:X_{0.5}\longrightarrow X_{\alpha}$, because if exists then must exist an  open connected set $A$ of $X_{\alpha}$ (i.e. a piece of curve) such that $f^{-1}_{\alpha}(A)$ is open connected set $Α$ of $X_{0.5}$ with $(0,0)\in f^{-1}_{\alpha}(A)$, which cannot happened because $(0,0)$ is an intersection point of $X_{0.5}$ ($f^{-1}_{\alpha}(A)$ is the union of two crossed pieces of curves).

Secondly, for $\alpha\in({-1,1})$, we observe that the maps   $f_{\alpha}:X_{0.5}\longrightarrow X_{\alpha}$  with
\begin{align*}
 &\begin{pmatrix}
  2\big({0.5-\cos({t+\arccos{0.5}})}\big)\,\cos({t+\arccos{0.5}})\\
  2\big({0.5-\cos({t+\arccos{0.5}})}\big)\,\sin({t+\arccos{0.5}})
 \end{pmatrix}
 \longmapsto\\
 &\hspace{1.5cm} f_{\alpha}\big({x(t),y(t)}\big)=\begin{pmatrix}
  2\big({\alpha-\cos({t+\arccos{\alpha}})}\big)\,\cos({t+\arccos{\alpha}})\\ 2\big({\alpha-\cos({t+\arccos{\alpha}})}\big)\,\sin({t+\arccos{\alpha}})
 \end{pmatrix}\,,\;t\in[0,2\pi)\,,
\end{align*}
and
$g_{\alpha}:X_{\alpha}\longrightarrow X_{0.5}$  with
\begin{align*}
 &\begin{pmatrix}
  2\big({\alpha-\cos({t+\arccos{\alpha}})}\big)\,\cos({t+\arccos{\alpha}})\\ 2\big({\alpha-\cos({t+\arccos{\alpha}})}\big)\,\sin({t+\arccos{\alpha}})
 \end{pmatrix}\longmapsto\\
 &\hspace{1.5cm} g_{\alpha}\big({u(t),v(t)}\big)=\begin{pmatrix}
  2\big({0.5-\cos({t+\arccos{0.5}})}\big)\,\cos({t+\arccos{0.5}})\\
  2\big({0.5-\cos({t+\arccos{0.5}})}\big)\,\sin({t+\arccos{0.5}})
 \end{pmatrix}\,,\;t\in[0,2\pi)\,,
\end{align*}
are continuous* -it's sufficient to observe that $f_{\alpha}(0,0)=(0,0)$ and $g_{\alpha}(0,0)=(0,0)$- with $f_{\alpha}\circ g_{\alpha}={\rm{id}}_{X_{\alpha}}$ and  $g_{\alpha}\circ f_{\alpha}={\rm{id}}_{X_{0.5}}$. Therefore, for every  $\alpha\in({-1,1})$, the pair $({f_{\alpha}, g_{\alpha}})$  is a homotopy-equivalence.

(*) In fact they are homeomorphisms with $f^{-1}_{\alpha}= g_{\alpha}$.